How to integrate google adMob with google Ad Manager
I need to integrate the google AdMob with Google Ad Manager Account. But while linking i cant find any google account in my google AdMob account How can i integrate these two things.
I have made the mediation group and neither find the google ad manager as ad source nor any google account link
